# Using SO API in open source project

Tags: support, legal, api

I want to make free open source chat bot using [SO API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to get some data.
Just an idea for hackathon, not a business project.

Are there any chances it will get me in legal trouble with SO administration?
I asked about it via "Contact us" form, but got no answer.

Comment: You must name it for a seawater fish, (tuna is already taken).

Comment: The API has a terms of use. So long as you abide by that, you should have no problems.

Comment: There is already a open-source chat bot called [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) that monitors for spam and posts it at [the charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11540/charcoal-hq), so your idea would also be allowed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you'll be fine, as long as you follow the [API Terms of Use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use). You should also read [Throttles](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) section of the documentation for info on the rate-limiting system, if you intend to make a lot of requests.

If you republish or use user-created content from Stack Exchange, it's important to attribute both the users who created it, as well as SE, as described in the Terms of Service.